# Logitech USB Wireless headset problems

Tags: usb, logitech-headset

I bought a Clear Chat PC Logitech headset. Its possibly the best headset I've ever had, and it wasn't cheap. So you can imagine my disappointment when I upgraded to a 64Bit OS , only to find out - the sound is choppy, but it works fine in 32Bit OS (win 7 RTM in both cases).

Logitech won't help me solve the problem, and I doubt if MS will. Is there any way I can fix this problem without relying on the "giants".

Any ideas would really help.

The device uses the standard USB Audio Driver supplied by Microsoft. Not sure if its a driver issue or a general USB issue.

Comment: I hope there is a resolution to this.  I have that same headset and will be installing W7 64bit as soon as it comes out.

Comment: Gadzooks - its already out - if you have MSDN or technet subscription. So when I'm talking about Win7, I've installed the real thing (retail final) not some Beta or RC. And I can confirm - Go 64Bit dude... problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have discovered after 4 days of day and night searching for this solution....

GUYS I HAVE THE ANSWER (Hope it works for you too).

Firstly it has nothing to do with 32bit or 64Bit. I figured this out, installing 2 clean systems, and installing drivers 1 by one, and software, checking everything.

I was also worried that it could be motherboard drivers, or even possibly an out of date BIOS, if you can obviously update your chipset drivers, and try get a BIOS update.

But still this didn't solve the problem....

Here is what finally addressed the issue for me....

!!!THE GRAPHICS DRIVER!!! I know its hard to believe but I'm using a laptop so I got my driver from laptopvideo2go.com , instead of the latest, I rolled back to an earlier driver.

Now everything works like it should....

Comment: That is the strangest fix I have heard of to an audio problem :)

Comment: Counter Intuitive, but I figured it out, since, after installing graphics driver and enabling aero, things went side ways.... with the right driver, you can enable Aero and have no problems...